# CSS or JQuery Fixed sidebar in website layout

Tags: jquery, css, layout, fixed

My website is setup with the content structure like this

```
<body>
    <div id="header></div>
    <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div id="content>
        ...
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make my website behave where sidebar stays in the exact same location relative to where it would be in my static layout. That it's to the right of the Content column, that it's below the header div and above the footer div and that if they shrink the window horizontally that it doesn't move on top of the content column.

I've tried google generic css fixed position etc and haven't been able to find anything that was really working with me so that leads me to ask here. I'm looking for how to handle this with either css or javascript, if it goes the javascript route I'd most prefer JQuery as a base.

**Edit** I don't need to support archiac browsers but, I don't care if it works fully in ie6 as long as it doesn't ruin my page and degrades acceptably (like it doesn't sit on the wrong side of the page or on top my header or content)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end I went with a javascript solution where I started with before I came and posted here was

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#sidebarPage1').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
    });
</script>
```

Which did work and produced the result I wanted however it was very lacking in the effect it achieved because it was very jerky and unpleasant to watch.

I did some more googling today and came across this post: [Top Floating message box using jQuery](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/07/top-floating-message-box-using-jquery.html). Which lead me to here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#sidebarPage1').animate({ top: $(window).scrollTop() + "px" }, 
            { queue: false, duration: 500, easing: 'easeInOutSine' });
    });
</script>
```

Which produces a nice clean scrolling effect of my sidebar, the easing in my opinion is what really helps it feel polished.

Answer (score 2):

Try having your content div scroll with the content instead of expanding height wise and causing scroll bars for the whole page.  That way your layout will stay the same no matter how big the content is, and the content section will get scroll bars

```
#content {
   overflow:auto;
}
```

That should work for ya.

Comment: That is an option I didn't consider, i'd prefer for the scroll bar to be at the edge of the page like normal but this is always a possible fallback in worst case senario

Comment: You could always play around with the content area a bit.  Have a div inside the content that restricts the width.  Then have the scrolling content div extend to the edge of the page, then absolutely position your side bar over the blank area you have reserved in the scrolling box by restricting the content width.  Then your sidebar can appear beside the content, but on the correct side of the scrollbar.

Comment: The content and my site is all a fixed width layout using blueprint, your idea sounds very viable if no one else offers anything more

Comment: Yeah, its pretty ugly... no doubt... but its css... it usually is, LOL